# How to unit test a method which uses a static class which in turn uses ConfigurationElementCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

```
public class ConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
{        
    public static ConfigSection GetConfigSection()
    {
        return (ConfigSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
           GetSection("ConfigSections");
    }

    [System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty("ConstantsSettings")]
    public ConstantSettingCollection ConstantsSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return (ConstantSettingCollection)this["ConstantsSettings"] ??
               new ConstantSettingCollection();
        }
    }


    public class ConstantSettingCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {   

        public ConstantElements this[object key]
        {
            get
            {
                return base.BaseGet(key) as ConstantElements;
            }
            set
            {
                if (base.BaseGet(key) != null)
                {
                    base.BaseRemove(key);
                }
                this.BaseAdd(this);
            }
        }

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new ConstantElements();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((ConstantElements)element).Key;
        }
    }

    public class ConstantElements : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("key", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Key
        {
            get
            {
                return this["key"] as string;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("val", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Constants
        {
            get { return this["value"] as string; }
        }          
    }        
}
    
public class ConstantHelper
{   
    public static string ConstantForLog
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigSection.GetConfigSection().ConstantsSettings["ConstantForLog"].Constants;
        }
    }
}
```

Totally new to unit testing above is the code which reads some constant values from app config
here is my Code in the constructor have assigned the value.

```
public class HomeController
{
    protected string constants;
    public HomeController()
     {
         constants = ConstantHelper.ConstantForLog;
     }
 }
```

Test Code

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTester
{
 [TestMethod]
 public void Initialize_Tester()
  {
    //Creating Instance for the HomeController
    HomeController controller = new HomeController();
  }
}
```

while debugging found Appsettings are not read by the ConstantHelper class

## **Solution**

Found the solution actually it works fine mistake is done in app.config

Also another problem I faced is in ConfigSection
For MVC app web.config there is no need for namespace  **type="*type*"**
where as for unit test app.config there is a need of namespace **type="*type*,_namespace"**

Comment: has also added the app.config file to the Test project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to inject `ConstantHelper` into `HomeController`. You can interface it out and then inject it. From unit test pass a mock object of `IConstantHelper`.

**UPDATE**

I have defined an interface for ConstantHelper class to give me an opportunity to inject and mock the dependency.

**ConstantHelper.cs**

```
public class ConstantHelper : IConstantHelper
{
    public string ConstantForLog
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigSection.GetConfigSection().ConstantsSettings["ConstantForLog"].Constants;
        }
    }
}

public interface IConstantHelper
{
    string ConstantForLog { get; }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

Note I am now injecting the constant helper from outside so the unit test can mock it.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConstantHelper _constantHelper;

    public HomeController(IConstantHelper constantHelper)
    {
        _constantHelper = constantHelper;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_constantHelper.ConstantForLog);
    }
}
```

**HomeControllerTest.cs**

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index_WithDependecySetupCorrectly_ReturnTestString()
    {
        var mockHelper = new Mock<IConstantHelper>();
        const string testDataString = "TestString";
        mockHelper.Setup(z => z.ConstantForLog).Returns(testDataString);

        //Creating Instance for the HomeController
        var controller = new HomeController(mockHelper.Object);

        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(testDataString, result.ViewName);
    }
}
```

I use Moq mocking framework. Just install it using following command in Package Manager Console in your test project:

> Install-Package Moq

Hope this helps.

Comment: could u please explain a little with sample

Comment: thanks for the solution this also helped me,took two days to get the basics right it solved my problem.Above has some problem with virtual member

Comment: @Krishjs - Can you mark it answer if this solved your problem. Thanks.