# Writing Unit Test case for method returning action result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, assert, vs-unit-testing-framework

i did generate test case for following method; which returns Action result - a json "Success" string. How to modify the generated script?

```
   public ActionResult LoginClick(string username, string password)
    {
        LoginRepo loginrepo = new LoginRepo();
        BL bl = new BL();

        bool loginStatus = loginrepo.CheckLogin(username, password);
        if (loginStatus)
        {
            bl.SetSessionVariable("Username", username);
            return Json(new { Status = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new { Status = "Failed" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

following is the generated test case.

```
 [TestMethod()]
        [HostType("ASP.NET")]
        [UrlToTest("http://localhost:1280")]
        public void LoginClickTest()
        {
            LoginController target = new LoginController(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            string username = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            string password = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            ActionResult expected = null ; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            ActionResult actual;
            actual = target.LoginClick(username, password);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");

        }
```

How should i modify it so that it can run successfully? Since its an action result and the data is json string what should be expected,actual results?how should i write assert?

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

```
How should i modify it so that it can run successfully?
```

You will need to inject `LoginRepo`. More information with example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624465/how-to-unit-test-a-method-which-uses-a-static-class-which-in-turn-uses-configura/26624730#26624730)

> Since its an action result and the data is json string what should be
>   expected,actual results?how should i write assert?

You will need to perform a type cast like so to get JsonResult from ActionResult:

```
    var viewResult = yourTargetController.LoginClickTest() as JsonResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(false, viewResult.Data);
```